# Max WP upload limit won't change after editing php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, file, file-upload, size

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about this - I've been struggling with increasing the max upload size for my wp site for weeks now.

I've tried editing the php.ini parameters 'upload_max_filesize' (umf), 'post_max_filesize' (pmf), 'memory_limit' (ml) to no avail.  I need to upload files up to 500M in size and mysteriously managed to get it to upload somewhere around 410M max (even though I had 500M in the .ini file and the wp media panel said 'max file upload size: 500M').  Suddenly today I went to upload and it read 'max file upload size: 0 B' - I checked the .ini and it was set to 2M for 'umf', 0 for 'pmf' (something must have been written over).

I changed umf to 500M, pmf to 500M, ml to 1000M, restarted nginx via command line (the host is digital ocean, os Ubuntu) and the WP media interface still reads 0 B.  I checked my info.php file and umf reads 2M there.  The loaded config file path is '/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini' and that's the one I'm editing.  If anyone had any suggestions before I smash my screen w/ a hammer I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in your functions.php and see if it makes a change or not.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '500M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '500M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

If that doesn't work you can also do it in your .htaccess file for WordPress if you're using Apache.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan - I tried to add this to the end of both default functions.php and functions.php in the child theme I'm using but nothing changes.  The site uses nginx so there is .htaccess